# Excel Pivot Table aggregate by custom Cumulative Product formula

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, aggregate, aggregation

I really need help, I feel like I tried everything. I attach Excel sheet [on Google Drive here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yDhs820V4EFabAD4grwE8UWFPS9NjhbD/view?usp=sharing).

I have this dataset - Daily Dates and Daily Returns of the stock.
I added End of Month, End of Quarter, End of Year because I do {=PRODUCT(1+"RANGE")-1} based on the date to sum up by Month, Quarter, Year.

[image]

Columns H, L and P have correct values I need. It uses dynamic PRODUCT(IF(...)...)-1 but the formula itself is in columns I, M, Q (just for reference).

I would like to do the same thing in the PIVOT table and I spent hours trying to figure out custom "Calculated Field" feature, because it seems that this is the right way solve my problem. However no matter how much I tried I can't make the formula aggregate correctly.

[image]

You can see it in J14 through J23. The correct values are in K14 through K23 (same as my calcs in columns H, L, P). I think I missing something regarding the "array". For PRODUCT formula to work you need to use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER instead of just ENTER. This seems like an easy aggregation but I guess I am doing something wrong.

Please help me figure it out.Thank you.

Dataset sample to paste in Excel:

DayEnd  DailyReturn

```
1/1/2020    0.04%
1/2/2020    -0.89%
1/3/2020    0.68%
1/6/2020    -0.13%
1/7/2020    -0.71%
1/8/2020    -0.46%
1/9/2020    -0.05%
1/10/2020   -0.01%
1/13/2020   0.28%
1/14/2020   0.08%
1/15/2020   0.39%
1/16/2020   0.46%
1/17/2020   0.19%
1/20/2020   -0.08%
1/21/2020   0.66%
1/22/2020   0.15%
1/23/2020   -0.04%
1/24/2020   -0.12%
1/27/2020   0.57%
1/28/2020   0.16%
1/29/2020   0.38%
1/30/2020   0.10%
1/31/2020   -0.74%
2/3/2020    -0.03%
2/4/2020    0.93%
2/5/2020    0.12%
2/6/2020    -0.75%
2/7/2020    0.60%
2/10/2020   0.55%
2/11/2020   -0.60%
2/12/2020   -0.86%
2/13/2020   0.35%
2/14/2020   0.53%
2/17/2020   0.05%
2/18/2020   0.19%
2/19/2020   0.28%
2/20/2020   -0.25%
2/21/2020   -0.24%
2/24/2020   -0.53%
2/25/2020   -0.17%
2/26/2020   0.31%
2/27/2020   0.58%
2/28/2020   -0.10%
3/2/2020    0.43%
3/3/2020    -0.71%
3/4/2020    -0.13%
3/5/2020    -0.22%
3/6/2020    -0.29%
3/9/2020    -0.03%
3/10/2020   -0.11%
3/11/2020   0.47%
3/12/2020   -0.44%
3/13/2020   0.14%
3/16/2020   0.32%
3/17/2020   0.66%
3/18/2020   -0.59%
3/19/2020   0.08%
3/20/2020   -0.68%
3/23/2020   -0.94%
3/24/2020   -0.37%
3/25/2020   0.23%
3/26/2020   0.14%
3/27/2020   0.47%
3/30/2020   0.02%
3/31/2020   -0.05%
4/1/2020    -0.44%
4/2/2020    0.38%
4/3/2020    0.71%
4/6/2020    0.21%
4/7/2020    0.71%
4/8/2020    -0.69%
4/9/2020    -0.07%
4/10/2020   0.12%
4/13/2020   -0.60%
4/14/2020   -0.11%
4/15/2020   -0.38%
4/16/2020   0.05%
4/17/2020   0.70%
4/20/2020   0.38%
4/21/2020   -0.20%
4/22/2020   0.55%
4/23/2020   -0.47%
4/24/2020   -0.44%
4/27/2020   0.05%
4/28/2020   0.29%
4/29/2020   -0.31%
4/30/2020   -0.35%
5/1/2020    0.33%
5/4/2020    0.61%
5/5/2020    0.64%
5/6/2020    -0.54%
5/7/2020    0.17%
5/8/2020    0.09%
5/11/2020   -0.18%
5/12/2020   -0.02%
5/13/2020   -0.62%
5/14/2020   -0.37%
5/15/2020   0.53%
5/18/2020   0.54%
5/19/2020   0.01%
5/20/2020   0.09%
5/21/2020   -0.05%
5/22/2020   0.68%
5/25/2020   0.12%
5/26/2020   0.55%
5/27/2020   0.57%
5/28/2020   -0.33%
5/29/2020   0.02%
6/1/2020    -0.06%
6/2/2020    0.56%
6/3/2020    -0.77%
6/4/2020    -0.49%
6/5/2020    0.03%
6/8/2020    -0.37%
6/9/2020    0.42%
6/10/2020   0.10%
6/11/2020   -0.62%
6/12/2020   -0.44%
6/15/2020   0.19%
6/16/2020   -0.21%
6/17/2020   0.19%
6/18/2020   -0.17%
6/19/2020   0.05%
6/22/2020   0.20%
6/23/2020   0.13%
6/24/2020   -0.27%
6/25/2020   0.70%
6/26/2020   0.05%
6/29/2020   -0.42%
6/30/2020   -0.51%
```

Comment: I doubt anyone will open your google drive file. If you want help, I would recommend creating smaller, dummy data that is reproducible. Maybe someone will have an idea how to fix it.

Comment: Updated, thank you.